# Passing ManagedObject collection from fetch result to closure up to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I want to perform a background fetch and pass the result to closure. Currently I'm using `performBackgroundTask` method from `NSPersistentContainer` which is giving a `NSManagedObjectContext` as a closure. Then using that context I'm executing fetch request. When fetch is done I'm, passing the result to the completion handler.

```
func getAllWorkspacesAsync(completion: @escaping ([Workspace]) -> Void) {
    CoreDataStack.shared.databaseContainer.performBackgroundTask { childContext in
        let workspacesFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Workspace> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Workspace")
        workspacesFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "remoteId == %@", "\(UserDefaults.lastSelectedWorkspaceId))")
        do {
            let workspaces: [Workspace] = try childContext.fetch(workspacesFetchRequest)
            completion(workspaces)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
}
```

I'm going to call this method from ViewModel and use Combine PassthroughSubject to notify the ViewController about the event.

```
class WorkspaceViewModel {

    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    let resultPassthroughObject: PassthroughSubject<[Workspace], Error> = PassthroughSubject()

    private let cacheManager = WorkspaceCacheProvider.shared

    static public let shared: WorkspaceViewModel = {
        let instance = WorkspaceViewModel()
        return instance
    }()

    func fetchWorkspaces() {
        cacheManager.getAllWorkspacesAsync { [weak self] workspaces in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.resultPassthroughObject.send(workspaces)
        }
    }
}
```

And the ViewController code:

```
class WorkspaceViewController: UIViewController {

    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        WorkspaceViewModel.shared.resultPassthroughObject
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { _ in } receiveValue: { workspaces in
            // update the UI
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)

    }
}
```

My question is: is it safe to pass NSManagedObject items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [it is not](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_core_data_in_the_background)

> **Do not pass NSManagedObject instances between queues.** Doing so can result in corruption of the data and termination of the app. When it is necessary to hand off a managed object reference from one queue to another, use `NSManagedObjectID` instances.

You would want something like:

```
func getAllWorkspacesAsync(completion: @escaping ([NSManagedObjectID]) -> Void) {
    CoreDataStack.shared.databaseContainer.performBackgroundTask { childContext in
        let workspacesFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Workspace> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Workspace")
        workspacesFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "remoteId == %@", "\(UserDefaults.lastSelectedWorkspaceId))")
        do {
            let workspaces: [Workspace] = try childContext.fetch(workspacesFetchRequest)
            completion(workspaces.map { $0.objectID } )
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to make corresponding changes to your publisher so that it publishes `[NSManagedObjectID]`.

Once you have received this array in your view controller you will need to call [`object(with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506197-object) on your view context to get the `Workspace` itself.  This will perform a fetch in the view context for the object anyway.

You may want to consider whether the time taken to fetch your workspaces warrants the use of a background context.  By default Core Data objects are retrieved as *faults* and the actual attribute values are only fetched when the fault is triggered by accessing an object's attributes.

Alternatively, if the purpose of the view controller is to present a list of workspaces that the user can select from, you could return an array of tuples or structs containing the workspace name and the object id.   However, this all sounds like pre-optimisation to me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm trying to use MVVM pattern where ViewModel is responsible for dispatching different events to ViewController using Combine. I'm trying to avoid any sort of logic inside ViewController and use it only for reacting to different events with payloads. What do you thing about instead of passing IDs I will construct some POJO type of struct from ManagedObject and pass that instead with completion handler? In other words instead of `[WorkspaceMO]` pass `[WorksspaceBusinessModelStruct]`?

Comment: Sure.  You could use some other object.  You could also just avoid the use of background queues in this instance.  If you find the performance on the view context is a problem, then deal with it at that point.  Unless you are processing hundreds of thousands of objects I doubt you will find any performance impact using the main queue